# Почему не работает ветвление?

Tags: python

Напишите программу для решения следующей задачи. На зачете по физике ученикам 10 класса было предложено 15 примеров. Зачет ставится, если правильно решено более половины примеров. Сколько зачетов было получено учениками? Если хотя бы один из учеников правильно решил все задачи, выведите YES, иначе выведите NO. Программа получает на вход количество учеников в классе N (1 ≤ N ≤ 30), затем для каждого ученика вводится количество правильно решённых примеров.

Вот программа при сравнении print(temp == 15) выводит True
В условном блоке не работает(!)

```
N = int(input())
i = 0
count = 0
msg = "YES"
while i < N:
    temp = int(input())
    if temp == 15:
        msg = "YES"
    else:
        msg = "NO"
    if temp >= 8 and temp < 15:
        count = count + 1
    i=i+1
print(count)
print(msg)
```

спасибо всем за ответы! Получилось вот так:

```
N = int(input())
i = 0
count = 0
array = []
while i < N:
    temp = int(input())
    if temp >= 8 and temp <= 15:
        count = count + 1
    if temp == 15:
        array.append(temp)
    i=i+1
print(count)
if len(array) > 0:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что у вас переприсваивается значение `msg` _после того_, как был найден первый студент, решивший все задачи.

Comment: спасибо, вам большое

Comment: У вас есть ещё один баг в начальном коде, смотрите [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1542572/386633)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кроме проблемы с переприсваиванием `msg` у вас неправильно подсчитывается число студентов, получивших зачёт, так как в переменной `count` НЕ учитываются студенты, ответившие на все вопросы.

Другие замечания:

- имеет смысл завести некую переменную-флажок для обнаружения знатоков и устанавливать этот флажок при помощи оператора `|` (or)
- цикл `while` в данном случае лучше заменить на более лаконичный `for i in range(N)`
- условие в `if` можно переписать в сокращенной форме `if 8 <= temp <= 15:`
- для вывода сообщения о наличии знатоков можно использовать тернарный оператор

Получится что-то вроде:

```py
N = int(input())
count = 0
found15 = False

for i in range(N):
    temp = int(input())
    found15 |= temp == 15
    if 8 <= temp <= 15:
        count += 1

print(count)
print("YES" if found15 else "NO")
```

Comment: тест мой код прошел, но ваш код лучше:-)

Comment: На стековерфлоу побеждают не лучшие, а более быстрые

Comment: Буду в курсе:-)

Answer (score 2):

У вас неправильная логика. Если нужно определить, что хотя бы один ученик решил 15 задач, то не нужно сбрасывать сообщение в "NO" на следующем ученике. А начальное значение как раз нужно установить "NO"

```
msg = "NO"
while i < N:
    temp = int(input())
    if temp == 15:
        msg = "YES"
    if 8 <= temp <= 15:
        count = count + 1
    i=i+1
```

Comment: Спасибо! Разобралась

Comment: Точно, спасибо.